# Thumbturn cylinder fell out on inside

Tags: front-door

My house has front double door with a cylinder lock which I rerely use from outside (I use garage entry most of time). But I do use the thumbturn inside to open the door frequently.

The lock was installed more than 10 years ago and I never had problems until recently. First thing I noticed was that the entire lock started to turn slightly inside the door hole. Then it became more and more loose in the door hole until the entire lock was turning with the tumbturn.

Finally, the thumbturn fell off on inside floor (see the picture.)I thought that it was just some screws needed to be tightened but now I don't understand how it was working in the first place and what is missing.

First of all, I understand that the grooves on both sides of the cylinder are designed to stop it from turning inside the door hole. But my door does not have any fix screws for that purpose. All I have on the lock side of the door are two screws holding the brass plate (so how was it fixed before?)I can still operate the lock with the key from outside, and from inside by turning the key slot.

So the outside part is fixed inside the door hole. Only the thumbturn cylinder came loose.I don't understand how the so called Adams Rite Cam supposed to turn the key slot from inside. There are no push lever or anything inside. The tumbturn cylinder fell off when I was using it last time and nothing fell on the floor besides the cylinder and cover. It is a "period brass" lock made in USA with number 156 after USA and have no model number or original box.

[image: inside thumbturn cylinder]May be if someone can explain to me how the "rite cam" supposed to operate, I can figure what is missing and how the tumbturn cylinder was fixed in the door hole. I can see that "rite cam" turns inside with the tumbturn and extends outside the cylinder when turned. But I can't comprehend what it does but that.

Comment: Did you forget the photo?

Comment: walloftextishardtoread.

Comment: Please feel free to [edit] this into some readable paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

When the tumbturn rotates counterclockwise, the  cam's left side extends outside the cylinder and it's straight edge moves down and pushes a little pin on its way under the cylinder. This pin is attached to the lever that moves the deadbolt (see picture[image: circular plates]).

I couldn't see the little pin because it is below the lower inner edge of circular plate inside and is invisible util you look under it. I had to lose thee screws holding the outer cylinder attached to the circular plates(see second picture)

When I removed the three screws, the outer cylinder fell off and could see exactly the same extending edge and another small pin in opposite side of the lever pushing the deadbolt (now I think that lever is what is called "cam").

This why this lock is called double cylinder lock. The outer cylinder has the same parts as the inner cylinder, only on opposite sides. So the both operate the same lever ("cam") moving the deadbolt back and force.

The problem was that the three screws holding the outer cylinder attached to circular plates on other side of the deadbolt - are pushing on the deadbolt sides arresting it's movement, if the are screwed too tight. I had to carefully balance all three screws to allow deadbolt to move freely.[image: circular plates with three screws]

Comment: It was almost impossible to describe this mechanism without schematics or a video

Comment: https://youtu.be/6Vn55HWiBPI?si=P4QwGvZsxNboDNFt

Answer (score 1):

First: It isn't a "rite cam". Adams Rite is a brand name. You need a cam correctly shaped to work with the mechanism within your Adams Rite lock body, hence an Adams Rite cam.

Since operating mechanism designs differ from brand to brand, cam shapes differ, and the generic one that ships with a lock cylinder or thumb turn cylinder (if it included one) may not work well with your lock. But the cam can be replaced with the correct one; a store which sells lock cylinders should have the right piece. (A locksmith certainly will.)

Second: to access the setscrews that retain the cylinder in the mortise lock body, remove the cover plate from the edge of the door. Looking into that opening, you should be able to find the setscrew head, level with the centerline if the cylinder opening. You will need a fairly thin screwdriver to reach and turn it. Loosen it slightly to make installing the cylinder easier. Screw the cylinder into place (you shouldn't have to use a lot of force), and when it is tight to the door and in the right orientation, tighten the setscrew. Before reinstalling the cover plate you may want to check that the setscrew for the cylinder on the other side of the door is firmly tightened down, to keep the lock cylinder securely fastened in place  and maintain security.

Comment: I couldn't find schematics of Adams Rite lock like mine.

Comment: This the closest I could find https://www.tmhardware.com/images/product/D/specs%20for%20detailed%20images-281.jpg